# Passthrough Sonnet USB-C card to Windows guest via KVM and vfio

Tags: usb, kvm, pci, pci-passthrough, iommu

I am trying to passthrough a USB card to a guest, but I can't seem to make the VFIO driver stick, instead it seems that the host loads and takes over the card. I have a GPU successfully passed through, so I am sure that vfio/IOMMU are working.

card:  Sonnet Allegro USB 3.1, Two-Port USB-C 10Gb PCIe Card (USB3C-2PM-E)
motherboard: ASRock x399 Taichi
CPU: Threadripper 1950x
I tried following the same procedure that I used to passthrough a GPU, which I mostly learned [here](https://heiko-sieger.info/running-windows-10-on-linux-using-kvm-with-vga-passthrough/):

First, get the ID of the card:

```
~ lspci | grep USB
01:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ba (rev 02)
0a:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
0b:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) USB 3.0 Host Controller
45:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) USB 3.0 Host Controller
```

Next. get the vendor, product ID, and an alias, then modify system files accordingly in hopes that it will prevent the card from being grabbed by the host:

```
~ lspci -nn | grep 0a:00
0a:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1b21:1242]
cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0a:00.0/modalias
pci:v00001B21d00001242sv000016B8sd00007230bc0Csc03i30
~ sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
```

## paste at end:

```
alias pci:v00001B21d00001242sv000016B8sd00007230bc0Csc03i30 vfio-pci
options vfio-pci ids=1b21:1242
```

then:

```
~ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot and check if the card is using the vfio driver:

```
~ lspci -kn | grep -A 2 0a
0a:00.0 0c03: 1b21:1242
    Subsystem: 16b8:7230
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

I also tried making an override script as per the same blog mentioned above:

```
sudo nano /sbin/vfio-pci-override-usb.sh


#!/bin/sh

DEVS="0000:0a:00.0"

for DEV in $DEVS; do
echo "vfio-pci" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$DEV/driver_override
done

modprobe -i vfio-pci

#####

sudo chmod 755 /sbin/vfio-pci-override-usb.sh

sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
```

#### commented out previous entry and added:

```
install vfio-pci /sbin/vfio-pci-override-usb.sh
sudo update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

but still no good:

```
 ~ lspci -kn | grep -A 2 0a:00
0a:00.0 0c03: 1b21:1242
    Subsystem: 16b8:7230
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

also: When I look for the driver, in lspci (to see what else is using it), it brings up a bunch of devices but not 0a:00.

```
~ lspci -kn | grep -A 2 xhci
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
01:00.1 0106: 1022:43b6 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: 1b21:1062
--
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
0b:00.0 1300: 1022:145a
    Subsystem: 1022:145a
--
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
0c:00.0 1300: 1022:1455
    Subsystem: 1022:1455
--
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
46:00.0 1300: 1022:1455
    Subsystem: 1022:1455
```

Next I tried Tried blacklisting the driver:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

# original: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”amd_iommu=on”
# to: 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”modprobe.blacklist=xhci_hcd amd_iommu=on”

##then:
 sudo update-grub

 ##Uncomment in local.conf:
# options vfio-pci ids=1b21:1242

 sudo update-initramfs -u
```

still no:

```
lspci -kn | grep -A 2 0a:00
0a:00.0 0c03: 1b21:1242
    Subsystem: 16b8:7230
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

What else might I try? Am I correct that the kernel driver in use for that device must be vfio-pci?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a bit late to the party but I hope the following can help people on google quests facing similar issues.
*Please note I have only tested this on discrete USB controllers.*

xhci_hcd is indeed built in the kernel so it claims the USB controller and unless a workaround is found vfio-pci is not assigned as the kernel in use. One way to do that is to invoke  a script to bind/unbind

Another simpler way to solve this issue is to use the following command:

```
sudo driverctl -v set-override 0000:0X:00 vfio-pci
```

**Where 0000:0X:00 is your pci id.**

Upon reboot the driver assigned will be automatically be vfio-pci.

Answer (score 0):

Haha silly me, it seems I went through a lot of trouble for nothing, I could just add the card in virt-install and it appears to be fine even though the card isn't bound to the VFIO driver.

EDIT: It seems I spoke too soon because I can't passthrough my NVIDIA GPU and and the USB card at the same time (virt-manager just hangs without error when I try to start it).. but I guess that is a separate question since it's about two specific cards together.

EDIT #2: The trick was to install Windows with a different GPU and then setup the GPU passthrough by editing the domain XML.